# JavaScript code checking beyond JSLint

Tags: javascript, checkstyle, jslint

I'm looking for something that works like Checkstyle for JavaScript. I know about JSLint and I'm already using Google's Closure compiler, but these mostly check for syntactic issues. Checkstyle can check for braces on the wrong line, but it also makes it possible to write custom checks like don't use HashMap.

I'm looking for something like that for an upcoming JavaScript project. Any ideas?

Comment: Just to clarify, Checkstyle (http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) is a Java tool that helps developers stick to a coding standard.

Comment: PMD has some checks for Ecmascript. Also this tool provides ability to write custom rules by using XPath. Look to it, probably they can help you.

Answer (score 7):

Google Closure Linter: http://code.google.com/closure/utilities/

"The Closure Linter is a utility that checks JavaScript files for style issues such as operator placement, missing semicolons, spacing, the presence of JsDoc annotations, and more."