# Dealing with JavaScript in a large web application (reusability, bundling, unit testing...)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Maybe somebody can advise what tool, approach, reference I can use to achieve the following goals for a large web application when it comes to JavaScript: reusability, bundling, unit testing, many developers, stuff like that.  For example I've checked out browserify tool but there's practically no documentation, no book nothing.

Answer (score 2):

***Static Code Analysis:***

[JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html), [Google Closure Tools](http://code.google.com/closure/)

[JavaScript code checking beyond JSLint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882810/javascript-code-checking-beyond-jslint)

***Unit Testing:***

[JSUnit](https://github.com/pivotal/jsunit)

[JavaScript unit test tools for TDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300855/looking-for-a-better-javascript-unit-test-tool)

***Bundling and Putting It Altogether***

Java Based Builds - [Wro4j](http://alexo.github.com/wro4j/) - handles a lot of common web based tools such as JsHint, CssLint, JsMin, Google Closure compressor, YUI Compressor, UglifyJs, Dojo Shrinksafe, Css Variables Support, JSON Compression, Less, Sass, CoffeeScript...

PHP Based Builds - [What's your all-in-one web resource optimizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127443/whats-your-all-in-one-web-resource-optimizer)

***Multi-developer Environments***

Source control - [SVN](http://subversion.apache.org/) or [Git](http://git-scm.com/).

Project Tracking Tools, Colloboration Tools, Development Tools - See [Atlassian](http://www.atlassian.com/software) Products (JIRA, Confluence, ...)

Continuous Integration Software - E.g [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/)

Comment: +1 nice and comprehensive, re. code checking I would add [jshint](http://www.jshint.com/), re. testing have just watched [this jsdev intro](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/meet-crockfords-jsdev/) more info [here](https://plus.google.com/118095276221607585885/posts/CTZ7BNx7a8z)

Answer (score 0):

Try [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) for the reusability and bundling parts.

About unit testing there are a lot of tools out there and from what I see, it's linked to which ones you already uses and what/how you will test.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to be short because I'm in a hurry, but you should definitely use a **versioning system** (such as **git**, svn, hg) and you could also use [**yeoman**](http://yeoman.io/) because it has integrated build, testing and much more useful automated tasks.